# Are tabs allowed in a JSDoc comment block?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Is it allowed to use tabs in a JSDoc comment block?

```
    /**
     * Some description
     *
     * @function
     * @name            someName
     * @summary         And a summary
     */
```

Instead of...

```
    /**
     * Some description
     *
     * @function
     * @name someName
     * @summary And a summary
     */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems JSDoc doesn't have a specification which states whether tabs work or not. But looking at [The JSDoc website](http://usejsdoc.org/), it seems all of their examples don't use tabs.

**BUT**, I tried creating 3 functions - 1 with tabs in the doc, 1 with long tab spacing in the doc and 1 without tabs and use the JSDoc doc generator on them and it seems to work just fine.

The test functions I used:

```
/**
 * This function receives 3 variables and returns their sum
 * @param   {int}   myvar   - A number
 * @param   {int}   myvara  - A number
 * @param   {int}   myvarb  - A number
 * @return  {int}             The sum of all numbers
 */
function testwithtabs(myvar, myvara, myvarb) {
  return myvar+myvara+myvarb;
}

/**
 * This function receives 3 variables and returns their sum
 * @param   {int}           myvar   - A number
 * @param   {int}           myvara  - A number
 * @param   {int}           myvarb  - A number
 * @return  {int}                     The sum of all numbers
 */
function testwithlargetabs(myvar, myvara, myvarb) {
  return myvar+myvara+myvarb;
}

/**
 * This function receives 3 variables and returns their sum
 * @param  {int} myvar - A number
 * @param  {int} myvara - A number
 * @param  {int} myvarb - A number
 * @return {int}        The sum of all numbers
 */
function testnotabs(myvar, myvara, myvarb) {
  return myvar+myvara+myvarb;
}
```

So going by this, even though tabs aren't specified in the examples, they will work just fine and you are free to use whatever you are comfortable with